# Поиск самой длинной под строки типа "ABA"

Tags: python, строки, подстрока

Дан файл с буквами латинского алфавита, необходимо определить длину самой большой последовательности из `AB` оканчивающуюся на `A`.

Мое решение не подходит:

```
with open('zadanie24_1.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
    c = 0
    m = 0
    for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
        if (s[i] == 'A') and (s[i+1] == 'B'):
            c+=2
            if c>m:
                m = c
            continue
        elif s[i] == 'A':
            c+=1
            if c>m: 
                m = c
                c = 0

            continue


        
print(m)
```

**UPD**

Я добавил проверку на индекс, чтобы можно было получать только строки, которые начинаются и заканчиваются `A`, но это все еще не работает правильно

```
with open('zadanie24_1.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

m = 0
c = 0

for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if (s[i] == 'A' and c%2 ==0) or (s[i] == 'B' and c%2 != 0):
        c+=1
        if c>m:
            m = c
            c = 0



print(m)
```

Как решить задачу правильно и почему моя программа выдает неправильный ответ?

Comment: при парсинге строки используйте состояние, а не какие-то костыли :) так и программа более структурирована, и код расширять проще, да и понимать его тоже

Comment: Как выглядит последовательность из АВ, заканчивающаяся на А? Приведите пару примеров.

Comment: @Эникейщик `ABA` `ABABA` `ABABABA` `ABABABABA` ...

Comment: Напрашивается решение с two pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

pattern = r'(?:AB)+A'
s = 'qqqqABqqqqqqABAqqqqqqABABABABAqqq'
print(max(re.findall(pattern, s), key=len))
```

https://ideone.com/hdyRSO

Comment: важно, откуда это задание. если оно олимпиадное, вы уверены, что оно пройдёт по времени?

Comment: Мне еще сложно использовать регулярные выражение, вы можете привести алгоритм, пожалуйста?

Comment: Задание не олимпиадное, а школьное экзаменационное. По времени запас довольно большой

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

```py
def find_longest_seq(str):
    state = 0
    maxlen = 0
    curlen = 0

    for i in range(0, len(str)):
        curchr = str[i]

        match state:
            case 0:
                if (curchr == 'A'):
                    curlen += 1
                    state = 1
            case 1:
                if (curchr == 'B'):
                    curlen += 1
                    state = 2
                else:
                    if curlen > maxlen:
                        maxlen = curlen

                    curlen = 0
                    state = 0
            case 2:
                if (curchr == 'A'):
                    curlen += 1
                    state = 1
                else:
                    curlen = 0
                    state = 0

    return maxlen
```

В пайтоне я не спец, так что не судите строго. Переменная `state` содержит состояние парсера:

- `0` — мы вне последовательности
- `1` — после буквы `A`
- `2` — после буквы `B`

Важно, что эта функция вернёт `1` в таком примере: `AAAAAAAAAAA` из-за специфики алгоритма. Но, думаю, добавить простейшую проверку на длину после `if curlen > maxlen:` не составит труда. Также алгоритм чувствителен к регистру, имейте это ввиду.

Если последовательность не найдена, возвращается `0`.